# Problem with pgfplots/pgfkeys: "I do not know the key '/tikz/use units'"

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, errors, labels, units

**Problem in short:**
I'm using pgfplots but I can't use units in the labels. I tried this minimal example (from http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/gallery.html) and get an error message:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[use units,
    x unit=m,x unit prefix=k,
    y unit=N,y unit prefix=m,
    xlabel=Distance,ylabel=Force]
    \addplot coordinates {
        (1,2.3)
        (2,2.7)
        (3,2.1)
        (4,1.8)
        (5,1.5)
        (6,1.1)
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Here's the error:

```
Package pgfplots notification 'compat/show suggested version=true': document has been generated with the most recent feature set (\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}).

! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/use units' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation. 
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.20   \end{axis}
```

**Background:**
I use Ubuntu 14.04 which comes with pgfplots 1.9. Since I got above error I upgraded to 1.10 and the first line in the of above output shows it actually uses 1.10. kpsewhich also confirms that:

```
$ kpsewhich pgfplots
/home/simon/texmf/tex/plain/pgfplots/pgfplots.tex
```

I realize I could simply write the units into the labels by hand, but there is another issue. I'd like to scale the x axis units since I'm importing data from a file. But pgfkeys fails to recognize the respective command as well. To demonstrate, another minimal example from the sourceforge pgfplots gallery:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[change x base,
    x SI prefix=kilo,x unit=m,
    y SI prefix=milli,y unit=N,
    xlabel=Distance,ylabel=Force]
    \addplot coordinates {
        (1000,1)
        (2000,1.1)
        (3000,1.2)
        (4000,1.3)
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Gives me:

```
Package pgfplots notification 'compat/show suggested version=true': document has been generated with the most recent feature set (\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}).

! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/change x base' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Missing `\usepgfplotslibrary{units}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although I dug through the manual and other examples I missed a library import:

```
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}
```

It works now. Many thanks to @percusse for pointing this out in his comment to my question.

Answer (score 3):

I kind of had the same issue in Ubuntu 14.04. I was trying to use pgf/tikz in a code like below:

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[blend group = soft light]
    \fill[red!30!white]   ( 90:1.2) circle (2);
    \fill[green!30!white] (210:1.2) circle (2);
    \fill[blue!30!white]  (330:1.2) circle (2);
    \end{scope}
    \node at ( 90:2)    {One};
    \node at ( 210:2)   {Two};
    \node at ( 330:2)   {Three};
    \node [font=\Large] {Four};
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

but then I had the below error message in texstudio:

```
Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/blend group' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. \begin{scope}[blend group = soft light]
```

apparently the pgf version is old and we need to update it. what I did

1. Downloaded [latest version of pgf](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/files/?source=navbar)
2. unzipe the file
3. made a folder texmf in my home folder
4. copied the folder tex from the unziped folder earlier to the new texmf folder

problem solved :)

Comment: Thanks. So your texmf folder contains the above latex file. Is it right? I have same problem and I copied the tex folder to my latex folder file but it cannot solve.